# Is a bad practice uploading DEVELOPMENT_TEAM to Git from Xcode?

Tags: xcode, git

I would like to know if uploading the development team ID to Git should be avoided.

Is a bad practice?

Can be dangerous?

Should we always remove it before uploading?

```
DEVELOPMENT_TEAM = "";
```

Which could be the consequences? (Worst possible scenario).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Can it be dangerous? If a hacker gets it, they might be able to push apps under your name or your company’s name, at least it’s a great first step. Depending on what such an app does, your developer account could get revoked.